# How to write actions for UIButton placed in every cell of tableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uibutton

i am having a custom tableview cell where i have a UIButton.
i want to write action for every button placed in tableview cell. tell me how to do it.
i have tried using tag but its not working as *cellForRowAtIndexPath* load all the cell at once so its overwriting the tag number.
please tell me how to do it.
following code i am using

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){[cell.viewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playMovie) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       cell.viewButton.tag = 1;
    }
    else {
        [cell.viewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playMovie) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.viewButton.tag = 2;
    }
return cell;
```

[image]

Comment: do you want to do different action for different button or same action for all button

Comment: different action for different buttons and i dont wanna use didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @jrturton its not duplicate. PFP in my question i have updated.
i am not using IBOutlet its just a UIButton.

Comment: It _is_ a duplicate. It makes no difference if you are using an outlet or not. You want to know which cell the button was in when it was clicked, right?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the instance of button also with @selector

```
[cell.viewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playMovie:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
cell.viewButton.tag = indexpath.row;
```

And then implement the button click method like this

```
-(void)playMovie:(UIButton *)sender{

  if(sender.tag == 0){
  NSLog(@"button at first cell");

  }else if (sender.tag  == 1){
  NSLog(@"button at first cell");
  }
  // SO on.......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give button tag to your button then you can identified that button in its method.

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row+1;
```

and you can get that in its click event

```
-(void)btnOnClick:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btnTag = (UIButton *)sender.tag;
if(btn.tag == 1)
{
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you add +1? Is their any special reason?

Comment: in tableview indexPath.row is starting with 0 thats why add +1 so it is start with +1. Nothing else.

Comment: Ya I can understand what you've done. But Even if you don't add +1, code should work.. that's why asked.. Happy coding :)

Comment: Ya i know then you compare tag with 0 in click event...

Answer (score 0):

`No need to add target for every rows`, Do something like this :

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
       cell.viewButton.tag = 100;
    }
    else {
        cell.viewButton.tag = 101;
    }
[cell.viewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playMovie:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return cell;


-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender{
if(sender.tag == 100){
// Do your Stuff..
}else if(....).....

}
```